# Opening the "Run a Command" prompt from terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome, shortcut-keys

My end goal is to bind a double-press of the control key to launch the "Run a Command" prompt that's usually tied to `alt+F2` by default.

I used xcape to bind `ctrl` to an unused combination when it's released on its own (like detailed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214956/how-to-set-a-single-modifier-key-as-a-shortcut-in-openbox)), then created a small script to run a command when it's typed twice in succession (as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471622/map-double-click-to-key-combination)). Then, I went to settings to create the shortcut and realized I had no idea what command to actually use.

In short - is there some command that opens gnome's "Run a command" prompt?

Workarounds for my specific issue are welcome, but now I'm also just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.openRunDialog();'
```

The above command opens the "Run a command" Dialog.